# How to copy data whilst changing column

Tags: excel, vba, copy

Me again... I've got some code that copies cells from a certain column (from sheet "Convertor") and pastes it into a different column (sheet "Unallocated"). These values (IDs) are then used as a reference point to move the rest of the cells for each row (record) into the correct position I need it in.

However I can't get the code to continuously copy the IDs into a blank row so that they don't overwrite the previous set. I think it's something to do with the line `Master.Cells(rowB, colB) = yourData` but I can't figure it out. I tried changing the `rowB` to be the same `xlUp` to find the last unused cell in the column (as with `lastA = Slave.Cells(Rows.Count, colA).End(xlUp).Row`), but I couldn't get it to work. Any ideas?

Current code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim colA As Integer, colB As Integer
Dim rowA As Integer, rowB As Integer
Dim Master As Worksheet, Slave As Worksheet 'declare both

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Unallocated")
Set Slave = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convertor")

colA = 17 
colB = 29 

rowA = 1 
rowB = 1 

lastA = Slave.Cells(Rows.Count, colA).End(xlUp).Row 'This finds the last row of the data of the column FROM which i'm copying
For x = rowA To lastA 'Loops through all the rows of A
    yourData = Cells(x, colA)
    Master.Cells(rowB, colB) = yourData
    rowB = rowB + 1 'Increments the current line of destination workbook
Next x 'Skips to next row

For j = 1 To 5000 '(the master sheet)

    For i = 1 To 5000 '(the slave sheet) 'for first 1000 cells

        If Trim(Master.Cells(j, 29).Value2) = vbNullString Then Exit For 'if ID cell is blank exit

        If Master.Cells(j, 29).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 17).Value Then

            If IsEmpty(Slave.Cells(i, 3)) Then Exit Sub

            Master.Cells(j, 2).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 3).Value 'Move all other data based on the ID
            Master.Cells(j, 8).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 4).Value
            Master.Cells(j, 9).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 5).Value
            Master.Cells(j, 10).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 6).Value
            Master.Cells(j, 11).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 7).Value
            Master.Cells(j, 12).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 8).Value
            Master.Cells(j, 13).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 9).Value
            Master.Cells(j, 4).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 10).Value
            Master.Cells(j, 23).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 11).Value
            Master.Cells(j, 24).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 12).Value
            Master.Cells(j, 25).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 13).Value
            Master.Cells(j, 26).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 14).Value
            Master.Cells(j, 27).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 15).Value
            Master.Cells(j, 28).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 16).Value

            If Not IsEmpty(Slave.Cells(i, 3)) Then _
            Slave.Cells(i, 3).EntireRow.Delete 'deletes row after it has been copied

        End If
    Next

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you not doing all the copying in the same loop?

Comment: I wasn't quite sure how. Originally I was working on static values (the ID) were used as an anchor point to move the rest of the data (second loop). However now the IDs are now only on the first sheet, so I figured these need transferring first to be an anchor point for the rest of the data. I use the second loop (values) as it seems to be the fastest method of moving large sets of data into the correct order I need. Thanks.

Comment: See my new answer. That will go row by row on the current sheet and copy data to the other sheet. We do it all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a simple loop copying data for each row.  Then you can add in your checks.

You can use worksheet.range to write to cells (column row) such as ("A4") or ("A" & counter).

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wsMaster As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim strValue As String

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Convertor")
    Set wsMaster = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Unallocated")

    'Count of row to read from
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = 1

    'Count of row to write to
    Dim jRow As Long
    jRow = 1

    ws.Activate
    'Loop through and copy what is in the rows
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        wsMaster.Range("AC" & jRow).Value = ws.Range("Q" & lRow).Value

        wsMaster.Range("B" & jRow).Value = ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value
        wsMaster.Range("H" & jRow).Value = ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value
        wsMaster.Range("I" & jRow).Value = ws.Range("E" & lRow).Value
        wsMaster.Range("J" & jRow).Value = ws.Range("F" & lRow).Value
        wsMaster.Range("K" & jRow).Value = ws.Range("G" & lRow).Value
        wsMaster.Range("L" & jRow).Value = ws.Range("H" & lRow).Value
        wsMaster.Range("M" & jRow).Value = ws.Range("I" & lRow).Value
        wsMaster.Range("D" & jRow).Value = ws.Range("J" & lRow).Value
        wsMaster.Range("W" & jRow).Value = ws.Range("K" & lRow).Value
        wsMaster.Range("X" & jRow).Value = ws.Range("L" & lRow).Value
        wsMaster.Range("Y" & jRow).Value = ws.Range("M" & lRow).Value
        wsMaster.Range("Z" & jRow).Value = ws.Range("N" & lRow).Value
        wsMaster.Range("AA" & jRow).Value = ws.Range("O" & lRow).Value
        wsMaster.Range("AB" & jRow).Value = ws.Range("P" & lRow).Value

        ws.Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Delete

        'Increment counters for both sheets. We can actually use just one counter, but if there is ever a condition that will cause us to not copy a row, then we will need two counters.
        jRow = jRow + 1
        'lRow = lRow + 1 'This is commented out because we are deleting rows after we copy them.

    Loop
End Sub
```

If you really need to delete the rows after they are copied then we will have to not increment the lRow value.

Comment: HI @MatthewD Yeah unfortunately I need the rows to be deleted after the copying, as the "Convertor" sheet will have large amounts of data being input everyday, so it'll need to clear itself. Unless maybe at the end of all the loops of copying, just add a select cells with data and delete kind of code? or simply add in a clearing loop to remove all data from the previously mentioned columns for each cell?

Comment: If every row will get deleted everyday. You can go ahead and just remove the lrow = lrow + 1, then it will copy lRow (which will be 1) and then delete it and then copy lrow again (which will be the next row that moved up).

Comment: Brilliant thanks @MatthewD. This current code is endless apparently as I think it looks through the whole sheet. Would adding an if statement for ID using IsEmpty() before the jRow = jRow + 1  work? Also, if used more than once it overwrites the previous data on the "Unallocated" sheet. To prevent this would I simply add a row xlUp counter to the jRow =? Thanks again!

Comment: I managed to get the code to work. I changed lRow to 2 (to prevent it from touching the heading, sorry I didn't specify that), Change ` jRow = 1` to `jRow = wsMaster.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1` to write successive rows on "Unallocated" sheet, and added the if statement `If Worksheets("Convertor").Range("B" & lRow) = vbNullString Then Exit Do` in between `ws.Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Delete` and `jRow = jRow + 1` to add a stop into the loops. Thanks for all your help @MatthewD!

Answer (score 0):

.Cells is Limiting your approach.

Consider Change to Using Range("A1:C3000") notation it's more powerful.

Range.Select
Range.Paste (to new High mark for UsedRows.Count at destination)

Also unless you have exactly 5000 rows, it's not that accurate,

experiment with

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Comment: I used `.Cells` in the second large looping section to move the values into the correct order I need them in (hence the sheetname "Convertor"), as I didn't know how to do it any other way. And i'll be honest, I got the first part (that uses all the `colA` and `rowB` from the internet.